# apple In-App Purchase server call back JSON does not contain a “latest_receipt_info” key?

Tags: ios

before 2019-05-29 the callback json have  “latest_receipt_info” key, but today the callback json does have any receipt info  example:

```
    {
  "auto_renew_product_id": "com.xx.xx",
  "notification_type": "DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS",
  "environment": "PROD",
  "password": "xxxxx",
  "auto_renew_status_change_date_ms": "1559178490000",
  "auto_renew_status_change_date_pst": "2019-05-29 18:08:10 America/Los_Angeles",
  "auto_renew_status_change_date": "2019-05-30 01:08:10 Etc/GMT",
  "auto_renew_status": "false"
}
```

Comment: We are STILL experiencing this in the Sandbox environment... We can't test our system properly.
Apple is taking 30% of our revenue for this...

Answer (score 0):

According to the apple documentation "latest_receipt_info" is the JSON representation of the receipt for the most recent renewal. Posted only if renewal is successful. Not posted for notification_type CANCEL. See more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW16).

Answer (score 0):

I've started receiving these kind of notifications yesterday too, since about 2019-05-29 21:00 UTC, and it looks like some kind of malfunction, as they are totally useless without receipt or other identifying info. I've been receiving them for about 13 hours and now I see that normal notifications are starting to appear (since 2019-05-30 10:00 UTC).

So I think that was some issue at Apple, I hope it's been resolved.

Comment: Yes, it is restored, our service is restored at 2019-05-30 10:00 UTC, hope no longer appears